# Add users roles in Meanjs

Tags: roles, mean, mean-stack, meanjs

Recently I began to use MeanJs, it's pretty amazing but I don't understand some stuff.
I need to create a simple user management for my backend.

From official blog they say:

> New usability features:
>   Added roles to the User model - the defaults
>   are ‘user’ and ‘admin’, you can add and remove them as needed.

After a search I found some examples but all of these about meanio, not meanjs, there are a package MEAN-ADMIN in meanio that does it for us but in meanjs I not found.

Someone know the best way to implement a user management? some example?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28450348/mean-io-best-practice-to-extend-user-model/28569570#28569570

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The meanjs generator comes with some basic user roles built in. The roles is an array on the user model.

```
roles: {
    type: [{
        type: String,
        enum: ['user', 'admin']
    }],
    default: ['user']
},
```

To add a user with the role admin just attach it to the user object before saving.

```
user.roles = ['admin'];
```

If you want to use roles apart from admin and user you need to add then to the type enum.

Comment: hey @Banner , I'm, having issues with the exact thing. can you review this please ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33037901/mongodb-can-not-update-role-of-document