# MongoDB | Can not update 'role' of document

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, mean-stack

So I have this problem where I can not update a 'role' of document.
The document is a 'user' (the User schema in MEANjs) object and it got its pre-defined roles property.
This is the roles part from the schema :

```
roles: {
        type: [{
            type: String,
            enum: ['user','volunteer','participant','manager', 'admin']
        }],
        default: ['volunteer']
    }
```

And I'm updating it via regular PUT request.
The request returns OK (200) but nothing changes. 
If I'm using the same method to update another field (a custom one that i've created) it works fine.

Any clue ? maybe something with the enum here ?

thanks !

PS - document's version ( `__v` ) is off so nothing to do with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is indeed the expected behaviour since the roles are deleted by default as a security measure if you try to update the profile as a user, otherwise any user could just add roles to himself and get for example admin privileges.
The file where they are being deleted is `/modules/users/server/controllers/users/users.profile.server.controller.js` (in latest MEAN.js version):

```
/**
 * Update user details
 */
exports.update = function (req, res) {
  // Init Variables
  var user = req.user;

  // For security measurement we remove the roles from the req.body object
  delete req.body.roles;

  ...
```

In the latest MEAN.js version you can change any user role if you have admin privileges (check file the `modules/users/server/controllers/admin.server.controller.js`):

```
/**
 * Update a User
 */
exports.update = function (req, res) {
  var user = req.model;

  //For security purposes only merge these parameters
  user.firstName = req.body.firstName;
  user.lastName = req.body.lastName;
  user.displayName = user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName;
  user.roles = req.body.roles;

  user.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
      });
    }

    res.json(user);
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks :) realized it just before you answered it. thanks again :)